# Loss of saved/synchronized forms after re-installation of ccz file

Tags: commcare

Upon re-installation of a ccz file on a mobile worker's phone, users are losing all saved and synchronized forms. How can we ensure that saved forms are saved to the mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Saved Forms" functionality in CommCare is not intended to be a reliable way of viewing historical data (because as you experienced, this data is not re-synced to the phone after a reinstall).

In order to reliably make historical data available on the phone, you need to save this data to a case and then create a way for it to be displayed to the user (either in a form or a case details screen).